# Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash()

Tags: php

Here's my error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash() in /Applications/mampstack-5.4.25-1/apache2/htdocs/php-login/application/models/login_model.php on line 462

PHP line 462:

```
$user_password_hash = password_hash($_POST['user_password_new'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost' => $hash_cost_factor));
```

I'm aware that `password_hash` is PHP 5.5.0 and I am using it. I've tried playing around with it but could succeeded. Any help would be great.

**EDIT:**

It says `mampstack-5.4.25-1` but that's simply a name for it. I've upgraded. I've used PHP 5.5.0  features just this morning.

Comment: What?!?!  You have PHP 5.4.24!  That is not 5.5.0!

Comment: Use the Userland implementation by [ircmaxell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/338665/ircmaxell): https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: How would that be? I used PHP 5.5.0 features on other projects earlier today. @AbraCadaver

Comment: Dunno, but: **5.4.25-1** /apache2/htdocs/php-login/application/models/login_model.php on line 462

Comment: What PHP5.5 feature did you use? Are you sure it is PHP5.5 only?

Comment: Please tell us the output of `echo phpversion();`

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.8 @WesleyMurch

Answer (score 0):

as for your php version you could use this

```
$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$passh = crypt($pass, '$6$'.$salt);
```

$6$ means that its SHA-512 just remember to store salt in database, so you can check the password afterwards.

Comment: Your call to `crypt()` will return `$6$salt$hash`, you don't have to store the salt separately. Also, `mcrypt_create_iv()` returns a *binary* string that may not store well. `substr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), 0, 16);` will generate a random, 7-bit safe salt.